# Is usage of return value of laravel's validate important?

Tags: laravel

let's imagine this code.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
  $validated = $request->validate(['name' => 'required']);

  $post = new Post();

  $post->name = $request->name;
  // OR
  $post->name = $validated['name'];

  $post->save();
}
```

is it important to use `$validated['name']` as opposed to `$request->name`?

i was testing some basic sql injections and my app seemed to be protected even with `$request->name`

so is `$request` validated?

Comment: They should be the same, but you can confirm yourself: `dd($validated['name'], $request->name, $validated['name'] == $request->name);`. If you passed "Test" as the name, it should output `"Test", "Test", true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As **@Tim Lewis** said they are the same

because if the validation didn't pass it will not continue to the rest of your code inside the controller's method

the most common case to use the validated `array` is when you try to create new model or update one and you want to add each property manually so you could just pass it directly like this

```php
 $validated = $request->validate([
      'title' => 'required',
      'body' => 'required' 
]);

Post::create($validated);
```